# A gridview that consist of two columns named as Present and pres

Tags: c#, windows, checkbox, gridview, cell

The problem is I have a lot of rows in gridview but when I checked a certain or any Checkbox, I wasn't able to add 1 in present column.

I just try that whenever I click a any Checkbox under column name "pres" it Will add 1 in "Present" column that is used for counting number of time when checkbox checked... I just need a code that whenever in any row of gridview under "pres" column I check a specific checkbox it will automatically add 1 to corresponding "Present" column value

Comment: How do you think this is different from doing the same with columns named "Attendance", "Attend" or "Count"?

Comment: That solution doesn't work 

Comment: So kindly suggestion ma code ... actually I want to a window application form that is used for students attendnce... so inorder to check their no of attendance I preferred using gridview... so I. Gridview I filtering every student of certain class and then try to mark Attendance

Comment: So kindly suggestion ma code ... actually I want to a window application form that is used for students attendnce... so inorder to check their no of attendance I preferred using gridview... so I. Gridview I filtering every student of certain class and then try to mark Attendance

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What errors do you get? You did not mention the name of the counter column (in the other question), I Assumed "Count". You might have to change it to your real column name. And since you got a Null-Reference-Exception for the "Attendance" column, you might have to fix this name as well.